# Cities and Knights: Lose to a barbarian attack, but no settlements.

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

The barbarians come, and the player with the least amount of active knights has a city and 5 settlements on the board.

What happens?

The city would normally get knocked down to a settlement, but all of his settlements are already on the board.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You turn your city marker, and treat it as if it were a settlement. From the [Catan FAQ](http://www.catan.com/faq/4806-barbarians-iii-players-are-defeated-what-happens-if-i-have-downgrade-city-settlement-dont):

> FAQ - Frequently Asked Questions Barbarians III: Players are Defeated
>   - What happens if I have to downgrade a city to a settlement but don’t have another settlement in stock?
>
> Answer Turn one of your cities on its side and treat it as a
>   settlement until you have upgraded it to a city again.

Comment: In 3rd edition, the Sabotage card says to turn a city on its side until it can be repaired (Ore + Wood).  Turning a city on its side to mark it as a settlement as well can lead to confusion... best to use a different kind of marker when playing 3rd edition (e.g. put a coin under it).

Answer (score 0):

In the games we play I turn the city upside down (to act as a marker for a town) and declare the village supply to be at `-1`. The player will need to build at least two cities before (s)he can build another new village.

I tried finding an official ruling, but it does not seem to be mentioned in a manual.

Page 11 only has this, which completely ignores this not-quite-so-rare situation.

[image: Part of page 11]

[Edit] The computer game [Catan: Cities and knight](http://www.catan.de/spiel/catan-staedte-ritter-fuer-pc-und-mac?start=7) from Catan GmbH seems to agree with this.